# Android TelephonyManager getNetworkCountryIso when roaming

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm developing an app that picks up the country the device is in while roaming.

Looking at the docs `getNetworkCountryIso` should be able to give me that information but Ive no real way of validating that without leaving the country.

Has anyone any experience with this or know more about MCC and be able to tell me if it returns the country code of the network the device is roaming on or its home network?

I realise that `getNetworkCountryIso` is unreliable on CDMA and plan other guards around that.